# Logic for Flow for Custom Notification

Tags: workflow

Hi team I want  a logic for a flow like

When ever Some one downgrades  an opportunity stage like from commit to upside or pipeline I need to send a custom notification for the manager. the point where I'm struggling is that I'm getting a notification even i change the stage from  pipeline to upside I want to send Notification whenever the stage  is down graded from commit to upside.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this with regards a Record Triggered Flow?

Comment: @FelixvanHove yes..

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an issue with a flow's Decision outcomes configuration which is used to check the `Stage` change. In order to address it you may try comparing old `Probability` field value vs new one. If new one is lower -> send notification; dismiss otherwise.

Sample may be seen on the screenshot below.
[image]
[image]

**Note**: this solution relies on the `Stage` field configuration as its values would automatically update `Probability` one with what's configured there (see screenshot #3). If this approach would not work for you for some reason, you may think of creating a complex if/else logic in flow using Decisions, but it would require maintenance upon each `Stage` field option change.
[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this approach. because Probability percentage may change in the future. In that case, you have to make changes in the flow.
 I would suggest, to check in the entry criteria, if the Stage is changing and check old value and new value of the stage.

Comment: @salesforcewithfunforce, I can see your point. However, Stages comparios requires some sort of hardcoding of the Stage names and their order, which may be avoided with the solution I've proposed.

Comment: @RomanS. thank you for your response will try it out.

Comment: Hello @LavanyaBolla - have you had any luck? If so, were there any issues with the suggested approach or, maybe, this thread may be closed?

Comment: Hi @RomanS. I'm sorted out i just used the prior value  and now it's  working thanks for your time and help.